# Create Border-Style with integrated TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have to work with a 1800-Row-XAML-Definition for a single window and I want to reduce the amount of code drastically.

There are several control-definitions, which are repeated very often and I want to write Styles for some of them. One example is a Border-Definition with integrated TextBox:

```
<Border Grid.Column="2" Margin="1,1,5,0" Background="#bbc2ce">
    <my:RibbonTextBox  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                       IsReadOnly="True" Background="#FAFAFA"  
                       Text="{Binding Path=someViewModel.Item,Mode=OneWay}" 
                       MinHeight="0" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Arial"/>
</Border>
```

Apart of the Binding Path, every value is exact the same over and over again. So I wrote this Style for the RibbonTextBox:

```
<Style TargetType="my:RibbonTextBox" x:Key="StandardRibbonTextBox">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FAFAFA" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
</Style>
```

Now I want to write a style for above border, and integrate the RibbonTextBox Style. Here I am so far:

```
<Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="borderStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#bbc2ce" />
</Style>
```

Is there a possibility to integrate my TextBox-Style here? And if not, does somebody know, how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No. `Border.Child = TextBox` can't be styled together (unless you redefine a control template for parent, but then you are not able anymore to set different binding for nested control), but you can create two styles for either. Consider to use `UserControl` if you have to use repeatable layout (group) of controls.

Comment: @Sinatr: Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need the readonly textbox, you can use `DataTemplate` with `ContentPresenter` as coded below (replaced `my:RibbonTextBox` with simple `TextBox` for demonstration). If you need read-write, you have to provide some way of binding that allows read-write. This can be achieved with `ControlTemplate` (also in sample code).

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1">
    <Grid.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="StandardRibbonTextBox">
            <!--Changed that one from HorizontalAlignment, in comparison to the question-->
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FAFAFA" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="borderStyle">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#bbc2ce" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,1,5,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
        </Style>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="borderedTextboxTemplate" DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <Border Style="{StaticResource borderStyle}">
                <!--This is not going to work for two way binding (IsReadOnly="False" and Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay}")-->
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource StandardRibbonTextBox}" Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="borderedTextboxControlTemplate" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Border Style="{StaticResource borderStyle}">
                <!--This is not going to work for two way binding (IsReadOnly="False" and Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay}")-->
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource StandardRibbonTextBox}" Text="{Binding Text,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="borderedTextboxControlStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource borderedTextboxControlTemplate}"/>
        </Style>

    </Grid.Resources>

    <StackPanel Margin="10">
        <!--Using Controls directly-->
        <Border Style="{StaticResource borderStyle}">
            <TextBox 
                 Text="{Binding Path=someViewModel.Item,Mode=OneWay}"
                 Style="{StaticResource StandardRibbonTextBox}"/>
        </Border>
        <Separator Margin="10"/>
        <!--Using DataTemplate-->
        <ContentPresenter
            Content="{Binding Path=someViewModel.Item,Mode=OneWay}"
            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource borderedTextboxTemplate}"/>
        <Separator Margin="10"/>
        <!--Using ControlTemplate via Style-->
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=someViewModel.Item,Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource borderedTextboxControlStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you.. And sorry for missing feedback !

Comment: @Joshit this one surprised me, thanks for going over the old stuff again ;)

Comment: for sure!! I am very thankful for support and its actually not my style to just dont answer.. The missing of an answer has some not so good reasons and I felt that I must honor the time and effort you put in your answer.. Thats why: Thanks for support ;)